# Review queue audit: what to do with obvious spam?

Tags: support, review-audits

What is the "correct" action in the LQ queue when I am presented with obvious spam?
[image] [image]

None of the options in *Recommend Close* seem useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's spam and an audit :/

Comment: Your screenshots are.... tiny? Not sure if that was intended or you accidentally just uploaded or linked some downsized previews, but I can't read anything on those.

Comment: That was on purpose but You are right, I've overdone it.

Comment: Also FYI don't worry if you fail a single audit, failing a single audit here or there is not going to be a problem :P\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you're sure it's an audit, anything would be fine.

Answer (score 7):

You could click the link to view the question on the main site to examine the post more thoroughly.

If it is really a spam post that hasn't been deleted yet, flag it as such. Or if it is not spam but otherwise bad but not fitting a close reason, downvote and/or flag accordingly. Maybe even leave a comment if you think the OP could fix the post or would benefit from feedback.

However, if your inspection brings you the realization that you spotted an audit (because the question is deleted already), just go back to the review page and use *any* close option. The reason does not matter at all and will not be checked. Pretty sure that attempting to edit the post would count as passed too. Just don't click on "Looks OK".